Dad wants to get a superhero toy for his son?
I had long ago watched a movie where there is a man who lives with his wife and son. The son is a fan of some superhero in the film and wants his father to buy a toy of that same superhero. That man being unable to buy one sees that their neighbour (who even eyes the protagonist's wife) has bought a similar toy for his own son and steals it. When his wife and kid come to know about it they are really angry at him. Then there is some celebration going out there where the Superhero is to come and by mistake the man gets a chance to become the superhero (as the main hero isn't available) and gifts the special toy to his son from the crowd.
I don't exactly remember things about this movie as I was a kid at that time but I really want to know it's name if anyone could find it out.

Hi! Do you remember the approximate year? The Country? The genre? (These often improve ID questions and the chance of getting an answer)

This was an absolutely perfect question!  I was going to ask the same thing :D  Thank you @Atticus

You're talking about Jingle All the Way. A classic Christmas movie starring Arnold Schwarzenegger. 

I knew it was Arnold but I still had the doubt because I had watched it when I was a kid :-P

You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details form the question in order to flesh out the answer a little more.

@NapoleonWilson What more is there to elaborate? He gave the answer and link to the IMBD listing. Nothing more to say here.

Well, one could reason in which way it fits to the details, so that it is clear why the answer thinks it's the searched movie.

But the question is very detailed. He'd be essentially copy pasting his details, and adding "Arnold Schwaznegger" here and there x)
